# Consulta EF devuelve 'query de consulta' C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Tengo una tabla donde guardo `ordenes`y `lotes`, cuestion es que trato de encontrar el `lote` si tengo el numero de `orden`, tipo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cuestion es que trato de ejecutar la misma sentencia usando EF y Linq, asi:

```
public string buscarLoteReque(string ord)
 {
      var dato = "";
      using (var ctx = new ModelContext())
      {
          dato = ctx.Ordenes.Where(x => x.orden == ord)
                            .Select(m => m.lote)
                            .ToString();
       }

       return dato;
   }
```

No hay ninguna excepcion pero la salida es esta:

> dev SELECT 
>       [Extent1].[lote] AS [lote]
>       FROM [dbo].[Ordenes] AS [Extent1]
>       WHERE [Extent1].[orden] = @p__linq__0

Algo estoy haciendo mal, pero no preciso que.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tienes que usar el `ToString()` sino el `ToList()`

```
public string buscarLoteReque(string ord)
{
      using (var ctx = new ModelContext())
      {
          var dato = ctx.Ordenes.Where(x => x.orden == ord)
                            .Select(m => m.lote)
                            .ToList();

        return string.Join(", ", dato);
      }

}
```

o si quieres solo un unico dato usarias

```
public string buscarLoteReque(string ord)
{
      using (var ctx = new ModelContext())
      {
         var dato = ctx.Ordenes.Where(x => x.orden == ord)
                            .Select(m => m.lote)
                            .FirstOrDefault();

        return dato;
      }

}
```

usando el `FirstOrDefault()` obtienes un solo resultado